# Custom browser in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

We're running selenium tests using as RC phpunit 3.6 and we configured a selenium hub with four nodes (using selenium version 2.25) 
I would like to know how is possible to configure *custom browser in node configuration, cosider that we're providing a json node configuration.
In particular, we would like to update the node in order to launch iexplorer with a batch file that clean up the cache.
Can anyone provide an example of the json configuration file and of the token we must provide client side in order to bind the session to the custom browser?
Thanks
Fil

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this setup work for you in order to have a clean browser instance? because it does for me...

[image]